# Endless loop in JavaScript that does not trigger warning by browser

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm displaying a set of images as an overlay using Google Maps. Displaying these images should be in an endless loop but most most browsers detect this, and display a warning.

Is there a way to make a endless loop in JavaScript so that it isn't stopped or warned against by the browser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/settimeout).

Here is an example:

```js
(show = (o) => setTimeout(() => {

  console.log(o)
  show(++o)

}, 1000))(1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a timer to continuously bring new images instead of an infinite loop. Check the `setTimeout()` function. The caveat is that you should call it in a function that calls itself, for it to wait again. Example taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp):

```js
var c = 0
var t;

function timedCount() {
  document.getElementById('txt').value = c;
  c = c + 1;
  t = setTimeout("timedCount()", 1000);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Start count!" onClick="timedCount()">
  <input type="text" id="txt">
</form>
```

Comment: You should use `timedCount` instead of `"timedCount()"`. There's not reason why you need to evaluate the function call instead of just passing the function in directly.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will set an interval and set the image to the next image from an array of image sources every second.

```
function setImage(){
  var Static = arguments.callee;
  Static.currentImage = (Static.currentImage || 0);
  var elm = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
  elm.src = imageArray[Static.currentImage++];
}
imageInterval = setInterval(setImage, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an infinite loop, make a timer that keeps firing every n seconds - you'll get the 'run forever' aspect without the browser hang.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using a timer which retrieves the next image each time it ticks, unfortunately i don't know any JavaScript so I can't provide a code sample

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo() {
  alert('hi');
  setTimeout(foo, 5000);
}
```

Then just use an action like "onload" to kick off 'foo'

Answer (score 0):

If it fits your case, you can keep loading new images to respond to user interaction, like [this website does](http://flickriver.com/photos) (just scroll down).

Answer (score 0):

Just a formal answer:

```
var i = 0;

while (i < 1) {
   do something...

   if (i < 1) i = 0;
   else i = fooling_function(i);  // must return 0
}
```

I think no browser would detect such things.

Comment: Thevs, browsers will prompt you if _any_ operation is taking too long. Your loop is not an exclusion. The only way is to use setInterval/setTimeout (as it has been already noted).